# OptaPlanner. What does "minWorkingDaySize" and "lectureSize" fields mean?

Tags: java, optaplanner, timefold

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v3W8d.png)
there are values in the json file that are not completely clear. I want to know what they are responsible for and what they mean

I looked in the optaplanner documentation, he did not find a clear explanation.

Comment: [Here's the constraint provider code that uses it.](https://github.com/TimefoldAI/timefold-solver/blob/main/examples/src/main/java/ai/timefold/solver/examples/curriculumcourse/score/CurriculumCourseConstraintProvider.java)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've checked the documentation: https://docs.jboss.org/drools/release/6.0.1.Final/optaplanner-docs/html_single/index.html

> Minimum working days: Lectures of the same course should be spread into a minimum number of days.

That's most likely your `minWorkingDaySize`. Regarding `lectureSize`, I have a feeling that it's an amount of lectures in the course. Look at the scheduling:

```
for (Course course : courseList) {
   ------------
   for (int i = 0; i < course.getLectureSize(); i++) {
       Lecture lecture = new Lecture();
       --------
       lectureList.add(lecture);
   }
}
schedule.setLectureList(lectureList);
```